# NHibernate mapping by code: Mapping userTypes by convention

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I would like to know how to configure NHibernate "mapping by code" so that when I map a property of a certain type, it uses a certain userType to perform that mapping. It figures this out by convention.

For example, if I have an `Account` class with a property `Currency` of type `Currency`, then the NHibernate configuration should figure out (by convention) that it needs to use the `CurrencyUserType` to perform the mapping.

I'm unable to find the relevant documentation for this, so if such documentation does exist, then a few links will be appreciated too.

Note: This is not a FluentNHibernate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
mapper.IsProperty((info, b) => b || info.GetPropertyOrFieldType() == typeof(Currency));
mapper.BeforeMapProperty +=
       (inspector, member, customizer) =>
       {
           if (member.LocalMember.GetPropertyOrFieldType() == typeof(Currency))
               customizer.Type<CurrencyUserType>();
       };
```